# Spring bean new instance of varing type according to lookup

Tags: spring

I have a servlet based application which currently uses an injected HashMap of command processors to process a user entered command. This works very well but I need to modify this so that each instance of the command processor is unique.

The new requirements comes from the need to "pipe" the output on one command into another so if the command processors remain a single instance "piping" a list into a list would be problematic.

I still need to be able to map the class that handles the command to the command text.
My first thought was the change the HashMap from mapping the command to an instance of the command processor to mapping it to the class name and using that to instantiate an instance of the class. But that does not work due to the need to configure some of the commands with for example a list of options.

I have looked at making the beans prototypes which would seam to do what I want regarding getting a new instance of the configured bean but I am confused as to how I can map this, was thinking I could use the bean ID.

I am now at the stage of complete confusion and cant think how to do this.

I am aware that the explanation is a little light but this is a reflection of my confusion and I suspect that the greatest help will come from request for clarification which will help to get the head in order.

Comment: Why cant you make your command processors work as singletons? Are you concerned about concurrency issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use request-scoped beans:

```
@Component
@Scope(value=WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST,proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class CommandProcessor {
}
```

You can just inject CommandProcessor in your code and Spring will make sure you get different instance for every user request. You also will need CGLIB on your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your requirements right you either need a [factory method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method) in your command class, or a [`FactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean) that creates the instances.